# pyinstaller: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RSA'

Tags: python, rsa, pyinstaller, scapy, attributeerror

**My python file runs all right with python directly:**

```
python detectIPConflict.py
```

**However, when the script packaged by PyInstaller:**

```
pyinstaller --onefile detectIPConflict.py
./dist/detectIPConflict
```

**Here goes the error:**

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scapy/all.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scapy/crypto/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scapy/crypto/cert.py", line 19, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RSA'
detectIPConflict returned -1
```

**I also have seek into the scapy/crypto/cert.py, in line 19:**

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import *
```

**I can not find why this error happened.
I'm get confused.**

**Anyone can help?**

Version info:

- Python: 2.7.6
- pyinstaller: 3.1.1
- scapy: 2.3.2 (installed by pip command)
- pycrypto: 2.6.1

Here is the detectIPConflict.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from scapy.all import *

def ip_conflict():
    ipscan='10.2.86.190/23'
    ip_dict = dict()
    ip_me = get_if_addr('eth0')
    mac_me = get_if_hwaddr('eth0')
    print "--------IP ME---------"
    print ip_me, "--", mac_me
    print "----------------------"
    ip_dict[ip_me] = mac_me
    try:
        ans,unans=srp(Ether(dst="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF")/ARP(pdst=ipscan),iface="br0", timeout=2,verbose=False)
    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)
    else:
        print ("   MAC            --   IP   ")
        for snd,rcv in ans:
            list_mac=rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src% -- %ARP.psrc%")
            mac = rcv.sprintf("%Ether.src%")
            ip = rcv.sprintf("%ARP.psrc%")
            # print mac,'-->',ip
            if ip not in ip_dict:
                ip_dict[ip] = mac
    for has_ip in ip_dict.keys():
        print has_ip, "------ " + ip_dict[has_ip]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip_conflict()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this error by modification of the python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/crypto/cert.py code:
Modify line 19,20,21:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC2
from Crypto.Hash import MD2
```

This works for me.

However, I don't know why 'import *' can not be recognized by pyinstaller. 
Grateful fort any explanations.